# Looking for formula to find x in column and subtract

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Not sure if this is even possible but looking for formula to look for X in a select column and if you find an X in column then subtract the value that is in a certain cell that is 3 down from the X and 5 columns to the left.

Ie:  look for X in column N (N1:N43) and if X is found in say N8 then subtract the value that is in I11 (3 down and 5 left from X) from the value that is in I44.  This would also apply if an X is found in N13, then subtract the value that is found in I16 from the value that is in I44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think the following formula will work:

> =IFERROR(I44-OFFSET(N1,MATCH("X",N1:N43,0)+2,-5),"Not Found")

The `OFFSET` function starts with "N1" (the top of your range to look in) and goes down until a `MATCH` for "X" is found.  It goes +2 beyond this to satisfy your "3 down" condition.  Then, it goes left -5 columns to reach column I, and so will be at +3 rows and -5 columns from the matched value.

The `IFERROR` function protects the cell in the case of it not finding a match for the "X", and returns "Not Found" if there was not match for the `MATCH` function.

Comment: I am wanting it to find an X in column N  and then if X is found to go 3 down 5 left.

Comment: or look for X and if one is found the apply.  if one is not found then don't apply.

Comment: @RickD I believe that is what this does, and it works in my test worksheet. For example, I have 100 in cell I44, "X" in cell N8, and 10 in cell I11.  This formula returns 90 as expected.

Comment: Sweet.  it seems to be working.  must have copied and pasted wrong somehow.  I might have further questions for when I taylor it to exactly what I need.

Comment: @RickD Good to hear.  Post back if there are more problems

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following in column I:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(3,N:N,1,FALSE)), 4, I44-4)
```

Where "4" is the default value of that cell.

`ISERROR(VLOOKUP(3,N:N,1,FALSE))` looks for an exact match of a specified value (in my example, "3") in column N. It will return true if there is no match and false if there is a match.

The second argument (`4`) will be populated if there is no match. Otherwise, it will subtract `4` from the value 33 cells below.